# Possible UI bug in Late Answers

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits, late-answers

Going through the Late Answer review queue I got an answer that needed editing.  There was already a suggested edit on the question so I thought if I clicked on it, it serve up a window to approve/reject the edit like it does if clicking it from a question or answer.  Instead it actually took me to the review queue and after doing my review action it kept going in the suggested edit review queue and did not count what I did towards the late answer queue.

Is this how this should work?  Since there was a suggested edit should I have just hit No Action since it was going to be taken care of in another review queue?

Comment: Not that this fixes the weird ui, but you can use the browser back button to go back the the late answer review after completing the suggested edit review.